# Does a greenhouse need to be built on agricultural land?

Tags: agriculture

Is it possible to build a climate-controlled greenhouse just about anywhere assuming that it contains soil-beds, a light-controlled , temperature-controlled and moisture-controlled environment and other resources needed for plants to grow?

Is there any advantage in installing such a greenhouse on agricultural land?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greenhouses can be built anywhere, so long as the plants within them are provided with sufficient nutrients and light. Depending on the crop, soil is not required if [hydroponic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydroponics) methods are used.

The use of agricultural lands is not a requirement. In urban areas, disused warehouses and other buildings are used to establish [vertical farms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_farming). Greenhouses are even placed on [roofs of buildings](https://myrooff.com/rooftop-greenhouse/).